# About employee who come out at night

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
EmployeeId       Checktime
1              2015-10-14 07:51:25.000
1              2015-10-14 18:56:47.000
1              2015-10-15 00:04:04.000
```

I want to get the minimum datetime and maximum datetime from this table. I want to give parameter for the program like this `'2015-10-01 07:00:00' and '2015-10-31 05:00:00'` and the `minimum datetime` and `maximum datetime` will show the result like this for all the month of that employee.

```
Heading    Minimum                 Maximum
-------------------------------------------------------------
16         2015-10-14 09:07:32.000 2015-10-15 18:02:20.000 
17         2015-10-14 08:55:56.000 2015-10-15 18:02:07.000 
18         2015-10-14 09:01:17.000 2015-10-15 11:37:10.000 
73         2015-10-14 07:51:25.000 2015-10-15 00:04:04.000
```

And my parameter was `'2015-10-14 07:00:00'` and `'2015-10-15 05:00:00'` but I want to pass parameter of whole month `'2015-10-01 07:00:00'` and `'2015-10-31 05:00:00'` and get this way answer for whole month.

Answer (score 1):

If I correct understand Your question this should work. I have provided a link to SQL FIDDLE:

```
declare @max_date datetime
declare @min_date datetime

select @min_date = '2015-10-01 07:00:00'
select @max_date = '2015-10-31 05:00:00'

SELECT EmployeeId
    , (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(CAST(CONVERT(DATE, CheckTime) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(MIN(CAST(CheckTime AS TIME)) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME) FROM table_name AS t2 WHERE t2.EmployeeId = t1.EmployeeId GROUP By CheckTime ORDER BY CAST(CheckTime AS TIME) ) AS  MinDateTime
    , (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(CAST(CONVERT(DATE, CheckTime) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(MIN(CAST(CheckTime AS TIME)) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME) FROM table_name AS t2 WHERE t2.EmployeeId = t1.EmployeeId GROUP By CheckTime ORDER BY CAST(CheckTime AS TIME) DESC ) AS MaxDateTime 
FROM table_name AS t1
WHERE CheckTime BETWEEN @min_date and @max_date GROUP BY EmployeeId;
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd199/2
DATA:

```
1   2015-10-14 18:06:22
1   2015-10-28 23:06:40
2   2015-10-07 18:13:58
2   2015-10-14 11:14:15
1   2015-10-14 19:20:11
2   2015-10-08 10:20:34
3   2015-10-01 20:25:28
3   2015-10-30 10:26:04
```

RESULT:

```
1   2015-10-14 18:06:22.000 2015-10-28 23:06:40.000
2   2015-10-08 10:20:34.000 2015-10-07 18:13:58.000
3   2015-10-30 10:26:04.000 2015-10-01 20:25:28.000
```

Comment: what is concat_ws and date_format is not recognised date formate

Comment: so what I use on that?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. and Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

Comment: this is MySQL, I wrote - it will be little different for T-SQL or Oracle or PGSQL ... because no information about database in original post - I just take what was close 

but it very easy to adopt

Comment: example not good in comment, if want can make thread in sqlfidle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6dfa/1

check please

Comment: P,S. my browser show me only - about-employee-who-come-out-at-night
and not "SQL Server", so it my mistake :-) if You can't update self, can help little later

LIMIT 1 = TOP 1
and same with all used function

Comment: Sorry about that the field was datetime formate so what I used on that date_format converting that into date or use dateadd function

Comment: still have the same problem